# Why my slider link url is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

the slider works, but not the links. Each slide should change the url

For Example :

1. **Slide 1** with Bing link,
2. **Slide 2** with Google link,
3. **Slide 3** with yahoo link.

I can not use **javascript**.

```
<div class="framebanner">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cdPVj2b.jpg" alt=""  usemap="#kitchurrasco" id="kitchurrasco">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/z3uurbl.jpg" alt="=" usemap="#rechaud" id="rechaud">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gZ4awVQ.jpg" alt="" usemap="#refrigerator" id="refrigerator">

</div>

<map name="kitchurrasco" id="kitchurrasco">
<area  alt="" href="http://bing.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,847,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="845,298,847,300" alt="" style="outline:none;" title="http://bing.com" />
</map>

<map name="rechaud" id="rechaud">
<area  alt="" title="Rechaud Banho Maria Aço Inox GN 1/2 65mm 9 Litros" href="http://www.google.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,847,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="845,298,847,300" alt="" style="outline:none;" title="" href="http://www.google.com" />
</map>

<map name="refrigerator" id="refrigerator">
<area  alt="" href="http://yahoo.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,847,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="845,298,847,300" alt="" style="outline:none;" title="" href="http://yahoo.com" />
</map>
```

**Example Site**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XboOXM

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are positioning your images on top of each other using `absolute` positioning, a single image is being on top and the link on that image map is the only one taking effect.

What you need to do is update the z-index along with your animation of the exposed image, In order to keep the visible on top so that it's link will work. Here's the new [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPXdBb) and the updated css is as follows :

```
           @media (max-width: 480px) {
                #espacoembranco img { 

width: 270px!important;
                }
            }


.framebanner img {
max-width:97%;
}
.framebanner img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 18s linear 0s infinite!important;
  -moz-animation: slideshow 18s linear 0s infinite!important;
  -ms-animation: slideshow 18s linear 0s infinite!important;
  -o-animation: slideshow 18s linear 0s infinite!important;
  animation: slideshow 18s linear 0s infinite!important;
}

.framebanner img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 18s linear 6s infinite!important;
  -moz-animation: slideshow 18s linear 6s infinite!important;
  -ms-animation: slideshow 18s linear 6s infinite!important;
  -o-animation: slideshow 18s linear 6s infinite!important;
  animation: slideshow 18s linear 6s infinite!important;
}

.framebanner img:nth-child(3) {
   z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 18s linear 12s infinite!important;
  -moz-animation: slideshow 18s linear 12s infinite!important;
  -ms-animation: slideshow 18s linear 12s infinite!important;
  -o-animation: slideshow 18s linear 12s infinite!important;
  animation: slideshow 18s linear 12s infinite!important;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
 25% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
   33.33% { opacity: 0;z-index:1} 
   91.66% { opacity: 0;z-index:1}
   100% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
}
@-moz-keyframes slideshow {
   25% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
   33.33% { opacity: 0;z-index:1} 
   91.66% { opacity: 0;z-index:1}
   100% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
}
@-ms-keyframes slideshow {
 25% { opacity: 1;}
   33.33% { opacity: 0;} 
   91.66% { opacity: 0;}
   100% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-o-keyframes slideshow {
 25% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
   33.33% { opacity: 0;z-index:1} 
   91.66% { opacity: 0;z-index:1}
   100% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
}
@keyframes slideshow {
   25% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
   33.33% { opacity: 0;z-index:1} 
   91.66% { opacity: 0;z-index:1}
   100% { opacity: 1;z-index:4}
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks man. ((:

Comment: in your browser you have bugs in transition?

Comment: I am using chrome, the effect seems fine..

Comment: I would like the fast and smooth transition (6 seconds)? how would I do?

Comment: I am not really an animation expert, but try to increase your keyframes and provide explicit opacity values, I bet this shall make it smoother..

Comment: sorry again, I made the changes. however I could not use the z-index correctly. Can you check? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzopM